# Scraping all tables from a webpage using python ps4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, datatables

I want to use beautifulsoup to get all the tables at this link `https://www.investing.com/indices/indices-futures`, following that I want to get the titles in the Index Column, and the Links of those titles.

I want what's in the first column only.

So for example.

```
title        href
Dow Jones    /indices/us-30-futures
S&P 500      /indices/us-spx-500-futures
...
Mini DAX     /indices/mini-dax-futures
...
VSTOXX Mini  /indices/vstoxx-mini
```

I use the following code

```
url = "https://www.investing.com/indices/indices-futures"
req = requests.get(url, headers=urlheader)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
table = soup.find('div', id="cross_rates_container")
for a in table.find_all('a', href=True):
    print (a['title'], a['href'])
```

I can see the table variable, but I can't seem the access the title (which contains the index name) and href (which contains the links)

What's wrong with it how can I get all the tables' entries at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `<td>` elements and get the `<a>` link under them.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.investing.com/indices/indices-futures'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

print('{:<30} {}'.format('Title', 'URL'))
for a in soup.select('td.plusIconTd > a'):
    print('{:<30} {}'.format(a.text, 'https://www.investing.com' + a['href']))
```

Prints:

```
Title                          URL
Dow Jones                      https://www.investing.com/indices/us-30-futures
S&P 500                        https://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-futures
Nasdaq                         https://www.investing.com/indices/nq-100-futures
SmallCap 2000                  https://www.investing.com/indices/smallcap-2000-futures
S&P 500 VIX                    https://www.investing.com/indices/us-spx-vix-futures
DAX                            https://www.investing.com/indices/germany-30-futures
CAC 40                         https://www.investing.com/indices/france-40-futures
FTSE 100                       https://www.investing.com/indices/uk-100-futures
Euro Stoxx 50                  https://www.investing.com/indices/eu-stocks-50-futures
FTSE MIB                       https://www.investing.com/indices/italy-40-futures
SMI                            https://www.investing.com/indices/switzerland-20-futures
IBEX 35                        https://www.investing.com/indices/spain-35-futures
ATX                            https://www.investing.com/indices/austria-20-futures
WIG20                          https://www.investing.com/indices/poland-20-futures
AEX                            https://www.investing.com/indices/netherlands-25-futures
BUX                            https://www.investing.com/indices/hungary-14-futures
RTS                            https://www.investing.com/indices/rts-cash-settled-futures

... and so on.
```

---

EDIT: Screenshot with `<td>` elements:

[image]

Comment: what does this part mean `('td.plusIconTd > a'):` ?

Comment: @anarchy `soup.select('td.plusIconTd > a')` selects all `<a>` elements that are under `<td>` tag with `class=plusIconTd`. `'td.plusIconTd > a'` it's CSS selector. The `'{:<30} {}'.format(...)` is just string formatting.

Comment: how did u find the plusIconTd?

Comment: all I see is this https://imgur.com/a/nEwjDCC , I can't seem to find the plusIconTd part

Comment: hey thanks for that I saw that, but how did you know to use just `plusIconTd` when the name is `bold left plusIconTd noWrap elp`,

Comment: @anarchy By observation - all rows that I was searching for have this class, so I used it.